# Controller not responding to Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In the home page of my application I iterate over a collection of tennis players (`@atp_ranks`), and for each tennis player I create a table row with his attributes and a button which allows the current user to enlist that tennis player:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Rank </th>
      <th> Player </th>
      <th> Points </th>
      <th id="atp_count" class="tennis_stats"> <%= current_user.atp_ranks.count %> selected </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @atp_ranks.each do |tennis_player| %>
      <tr id="tennist-<%= tennis_player.ranking %>">
        <td class="atpranking"> <%= tennis_player.ranking %> </td>
        <td class="atpname"> <%= tennis_player.name %> </td>
        <td class="atppoints"> <%= tennis_player.points %> </td>
        <% unless Time.now.month == 12 %>
          <td>
            <div id="atpenlist_form_<%= tennis_player.id %>">
              <% if current_user.atpenlisted?(tennis_player) %>
                <%= form_for(current_user.atp_selections.find_by(atp_rank_id: tennis_player.id), html: { method: :delete }, remote: true) do |f| %>
                  <%= f.submit "Dump", class: "btn btn-warning btn-sm" %>
                <% end %>
              <% else %>
                <%= form_for(current_user.atp_selections.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
                  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :atp_id, tennis_player.id %></div>
                                    <%= f.submit "Choose", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In order to give the user the opportunity to immediately see the result of submitting the form, I added `remote: true` in each form, and saved these forms as partials in `app/views/atp_selections`.

Then I created in the above directory the `create.js.erb` and `destroy.js.erb` files. Below is the content of the `create.js.erb` file:

```
$("#atp_count").html('<%= current_user.atp_ranks.count %> selected');
$("#atpenlist_form_<%= @tennist.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('atp_selections/atpdiscard')) %>");
```

The jQuery code should manipulate the `atp_count` id and the `atpenlist_form_<%= @tennist.id %>` id, that is the id of the fourth `th` tag, and the id of the `div` containing the button's forms.

Below is an extract of my `atp_selections` controller, which is too long to report it entirely:

```
  def create
    @tennist = AtpRank.find(params[:atp_id])
    rankings = current_user.atp_ranks.pluck(:ranking)
    atp_selections = current_user.atp_selections
    wta_selections = current_user.wta_selections
    if atp_selections.count <= 15 && wta_selections.count < 16
      if (1..5).include?(@tennist.ranking) && (rankings & (1..5).to_a).size == 0
        current_user.atpenlist(@tennist)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to root_url }
          format.js
        end
      elsif (6..15).include?(@tennist.ranking) && (rankings & (6..15).to_a).size < 3
        current_user.atpenlist(@tennist)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to root_url }
          format.js
        end
        ...
```

As you can see, the create action of the `atp_selections` controller is made of multiple if-else statements that respond to enlistment rules. However, what is important here is that in each condition I included the required code with the `respond_to` method for requests to be handled by Ajax.

However the controller does not respond to Ajax, and changes to `atp_count` and `atpenlist_form_<%= @tennist.id %>` are visible only after a page refresh.

The rails console reports the following error:

```
Rendered atp_selections/create.js.erb (223.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 695ms (ActiveRecord: 83.2ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `tennis_player' for #<#<Class:0x00000005948748>:0x0000000593f648>):
    1: <%= form_for(current_user.atp_selections.find_by(atp_rank_id: tennis_player.id),
    2:              html: { method: :delete }, remote: true) do |f| %>
    3:   <%= f.submit "Dump", class: "btn btn-warning btn-sm" %>
    4: <% end %>

app/views/atp_selections/_atpdiscard.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_atp_selections__atpdiscard_html_erb__451019467450256030_46643760'
app/views/atp_selections/create.js.erb:2:in `_app_views_atp_selections_create_js_erb__4477173780394533370_46811020'
```

`tennis_player` is the variable of the iteration and it seems as if it is not accepted when it is imported from a rendered partial.

Comment: Normally this happens because of **js code errors** in the page. Just check in rails server console if it renders `create.js.erb`, also first open any debugging tool in your browser and go to networks tab, check for any request-response cycle there.

Comment: I added to the original message what reported by the server console. The variable of the iteration 'tennis_player' when inserted in the form rendered as partial is not recognized.

Comment: You need to pass **@tennist** as **tennis_player** inside your partial: `$("#atpenlist_form_<%= @tennist.id %>").html("<%= j render 'atp_selections/atpdiscard', locals: {tennis_player: @tennist} %>");`

Comment: Thanks, now it works. For some reasons I do not understand, the variable tennis_player of the iteration is correctly handled when directly inserted in the home page, but it is not more recognized when imported from a partial.

Comment: From your home page you are passing the **variable tennis_player** to the partial, but when you call the same partial from within the **js.erb** file, `tennis_player` is not declared, and so you get the error undefined variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the same partial from within the **js.erb** file, `tennis_player` is not declared, and so you get the error undefined variable.

So you need to pass **@tennist** as **tennis_player** inside your partial from `create.js.erb`:

```
$("#atpenlist_form_<%= @tennist.id %>").html("<%= j render 'atp_selections/atpdiscard', locals: {tennis_player: @tennist} %>");
```